# How to force Intellij IDEA to use colon instead of braces for Scala 3 (Dotty)?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I want my classes look like:

```
class Dog:
  def bark(): String = ...
```

instead of:

```
class Dog {
  def bark(): String = ...
}
```

when I'm creating (generating) Scala file.

Is there any way to achieve this via settings or plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way for me would be to:

- create `.scalafmt.conf` in project root
- put there (among others) [`runner.dialect = scala3`](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/configuration.html#scala-3) and [`rewrite.scala3.removeOptionalBraces = yes`](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/configuration.html#rewritescala3removeoptionalbraces) (possibly with [`rewrite.scala3.convertToNewSyntax = true`](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/configuration.html#rewritescala3converttonewsyntax))
- maybe also add [format on save](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#format-on-save), though personally I prefer to add scalafmt to sbt and format on compilation

This way, yes, IntelliJ would create whatever it has in its templates, but right after that I would convert it to whatever my whole project uses.

Comment: Thanks, it does work! Although it turned out that it was necessary to add `version = 3.1.2` on top of it, too.